# Implicit Function Theorem Concludes the Existence of Explicit Functions?

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

On the [Wikipedia statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) for the Implicit Function Theorem (IFT), part of the conclusion is the existence of a function $g(\vec x)$. Is this $g(\vec x)$ not an explicit function for $\vec y$ of $\vec x$?

I am also confused by the statement in [the First Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#First_example) of the same article "The purpose of the implicit function theorem is to tell us the existence of functions like $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$, even in situations where we cannot write down explicit formulas." But if $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ are explicit functions, why can't we write them down?

Comment: not every function can be write down using elementary functions like rational functions or trigonometric functions

Comment: @user251257 Could you elaborate? If a function y of x is explicit, we must be able to express it, right? If you can give an example, that would be helpful too.

Comment: I meant that the IFT might provide a function that can't be expressed using known functions. Obviously you can't prove that without properly defining the meaning of 'an explicit function that we can write down". Also notice that you define a function implicitly or explicitly. But, a function does not have the property of being implicit or explicit.

Comment: Okay, maybe that's where my confusion lies. I thought implicit functions cannot always be converted to explicit functions. For example, $x^2+y^2=1$ is an implicit function $y$ of $x$ - however, this is not even a function, because there are multiple values of $y$ for each $x$. So it appears this cannot be converted to an explicit function (unless we place certain restrictions).

Comment: @user251257 I thought about this more; so IFT guarantees the existence of the function $g$, but it may be defined implicitly and may not be expressible using known functions. Am I right?

Comment: Also, I'd appreciate it you have any references or links to the concept of  "implicit/explicit" definition of functions...

Comment: exactly. ${}{}{}$

Comment: see Wikipedia on [implicit function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_functions)

Comment: Thanks @user251257. This is a bit off-topic if you don't mind: For some implicitly defined function, we can create an arbitrary name for the function, like $myMachine$, and that enables us to define it explicitly. So we can say $y=myMachine(x)$, which defines $y$ explicitly. But of course $myMachine$ may be extremely complex and may not be constructed using elementary functions. Am I understanding the meanings of "implicit/explicit" correctly?

Comment: basically yes. in fact most functions can only be computed iteratively.